# Gradually saturate/desaturate background image on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a project I'm working on with a full sized fixed background image. What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to have the image start in grayscale, then as the user scrolls down, the color becomes more saturated, until at the end of the page it's full color. I'm looking for a smooth gradual fade in/out of color.

I was thinking of having 2 images, one color and one grayscale on top of each other and change the opacity to get the effect, but that would mean loading 2 large images. Is there a better way by using only one image?

Comment: The two-image technique might be good for a fallback, but you can change image saturation (0 - 1) on more modern browsers with css. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of Your options are

1. do as you say and load 2 images
2. load just one and use a canvas element to do the desaturation
3. use the new filter css properties

Best to do a combination of option 1 and 3, using modernizr to determine support

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing this!